# MS Teams: Invoking outgoing webhook from AdaptiveCard Actions

Tags: microsoft-teams

In Teams, I have setup [outgoing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-outgoing-webhook?tabs=dotnet) webhooks to process messages with mentions to outgoing webhooks name.

Currently user is having to manually type in the mention to outgoing webhook (named `OutgoingHookName`) to post messages to it. I like to create an adapative card [action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-actions#adaptive-cards-with-messageback-action) in such a way that the outgoing webhook will be triggered when user performs the card action. I tried JSON as below, but the obviously incorrect/incomplete mention (`<at>OutgoingHookName</at>`) did not help.

Is it possible to trigger an outgoing webhook from with an adapative card action? If not, is there an alternative other than creating a full fledged messaging bot?

```json
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.2",
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "data": {
        "msteams": {
          "type": "imBack",
          "value": "<at>OutgoingHookName</at> ID:1234"
        }
      },
      "title": "Invoke Webhook"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently It's not possible to invoke an outgoing webhook from AdaptiveCard Actions and currently there is no work around for this. You must use @mention in compose message area for the webhook to receive message.

Microsoft will always focus on customer’s feedback and experience, some new features would be added to the services based on customers' feedback in the future, we also recommend you give your new idea in Teams UserVoice [here](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/) if this needs to be consider as a future request.